# StackOverflowError when trying to print a stacktrace

Tags: java, stack-trace, stack-overflow

I got the following stacktrace when trying to print a stacktrace to the console:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintStream.print(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:461)
at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:451)
...
```

Has anyone seen something like this before? What could have caused this? (Unfortunately I received the stacktrace from a user, so I can't say whether the JVM configuration was changed in any way.)

The method call that caused this was a simple catch-and-print, like this:

```
try {
  ...
  File canFile = new File(path).getCanonicalFile();
  ...
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Although I can't publish any more code, I can guarantee that the IOException was thrown by the getCanonicalFile call, because that's the only call within the try-clause that can throw an IOException.

Comment: Java documentation on StackOverflowError is 1 line, so I'm betting some infinite recursion is to blame.

"Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses too deeply."

Comment: `e.printStackTrace();` is not the cause. What's inside `try` block?

Comment: @gurung: `e.printStackTrace()` may well be the cause.  See my answer.

Comment: @gurung: See my updated post. e.printStackTrace() is called because it caught an IOException that was thrown from File.getCanonicalFile(). Nevertheless, I do think that e.printStackTrace() caused the StackFverflowError, because that's what the stacktrace says.

Comment: @pythondude `StackOverflowError` is not a super class of `IOException` and they have no relationship. Your `StackOverflowError` exception is  thrown from somewhere else!

Comment: @GETah: You seem to mix things up. I'm pretty sure this is what happened: File.getCanonicalFile() is called. It throws an IOException. The IOException is caught, and e.printStackTrace() is called on it. The latter causes the StackOverflowError.

Comment: @pythondude Mmm I think you are right here. The exception came through `java.io.FileOutputStream` which is kinda related to `IOException`

Answer (score 6):

If you initialise two `Throwable`s to be mutual causes of one another, you'll get a `StackOverflowError` if you attempt to print the stacktrace of one of them.

The following class demonstrates this behaviour:

```
public class StackTraceStackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Error e = new Error();
        Error f = new Error(e);
        e.initCause(f);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

We need two `Throwable`s in this example because it's not possible to set a `Throwable` to be its own cause.  If you try to do this, you'll get an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Alternatively, you can also get a stack-overflow error if you have a ridiculously long chain of cause exceptions.  On my machine at least (Kubuntu Natty, x64, OpenJDK 1.6), I found that a chain of 8000 cause exceptions is enough to generate a `StackOverflowError`, as the following class demonstrates:

```
public class StackTraceStackOverflow2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Error e = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8000; ++i) {
            e = new Error(null, e);
        }

        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

You may have to adjust the number 8000 on other systems.

Note that I used the two-argument `Error` constructor in this second example.  If I used the constructor that takes a single `Throwable` parameter, the exception message is populated using the cause exception.   This message gets longer and longer as the chain of exceptions grows, and as a result you are more likely to end up with an `OutOfMemoryError` than a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: I'll need some time to verify this. Thanks for the suggestion.